# C#.net to subtract hours

Tags: c#

Im using C#.net. I want to find the total hours by subtracting two double values. I tried the below code,

```
            double val = 150.20;
            double val1 = 30.50;


            DateTime x = DateTime.FromOADate(val);
            DateTime y = DateTime.FromOADate(val1);

            double res = (x - y).TotalHours;
```

The result should be 119.40 hours. But Im not get the correct answer. Can any 1 help me how to subtract two double values and get the total.

Comment: Try using `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`

Comment: If you need to convert, convert afterwards. Subtract the two doubles first before converting if you want a double value anyway.

Comment: Why should the correct result be 129.40 hours? There are months between.

Comment: So now you have changed the "correct" result from `129.40` to `119.40`. Are you sure that it's really correct now or is it actually `119.70`? If that is the desired result, why haven't you simply subtracted both double values from each other. The `DateTime.FromOADate` is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: if 150.20 means 150 hours and 20 minutes and 30.50 means 30 hours and 50 minutes, the result should be 119.30 instead of 119.40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if 150.20 means 150 hours and 20 minutes and 30.50 means 30 hours and 50 minutes, the result should be 119.30 instead of 119.40

```
    double val = 150.20;
    double val1 = 30.50;

    string[] temp1 = val.ToString().Split('.');
    string[] temp2 = val1.ToString().Split('.');
    TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(temp1[0])) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(temp1[1] + "0"));
    TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(temp2[0])) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(temp2[1] + "0"));

    TimeSpan ts = ts1.Subtract(ts2);
    double totalHours = ts.TotalHours;
    string[] temp = totalHours.ToString().Split('.');
    Console.WriteLine(temp[0] + "." + double.Parse("0." + temp[1]) * 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like so:

```
TimeSpan val = TimeSpan.FromHours(150.20);
TimeSpan val2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(30.50);
TimeSpan difference = val.Subtract(val2);

Console.WriteLine("{0} hours and {1} minutes",
                   difference.Hours, difference.Minutes);

Console.WriteLine("or, {0} hours in total",
                   difference.TotalHours); // displays 119.7
```

If by 150.20 you don't mean 150.20 hours but 150 hours and 20 minutes, then change the first 2 lines to:

```
TimeSpan val = new TimeSpan(150, 20, 0);
TimeSpan val2 = new TimeSpan(30, 50, 0);
```

On the other hand, if you don't need minute/hour arithmetic, why not just calculate

```
double val = ...;
double val2 = ...;
double difference = val - val2;
```

?

Comment: True... 150.2 - 30.5 = 119.7; reflected now in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting one date from another returns a TimeSpan which is encoded differently to a DateTime.
So when you convert the TimeSpan to a double you get a different number to what you might intuitively expect given where you started.

In this case `val` and `val1` correspond to the dates:

> 29/05/1900 04:48:00 and
>
> 29/01/1900 12:00:00

The resulting timespan is 119 days 16 hours and 48 minutes which when converted back to a double gives you 2872.799999

I assume `val` and `val1` represent DateTimes so just use the TimeSpan type to do the calculation as suggested elsewhere.

If `val` and `val1` represent hours then just use

```
double hours = val - val1;
```

if 150.20 means 150 hours and 20 minutes then go with:

```
TimeSpan GetTimeSpan(double val)
{
    int hours = (int)Math.Floor(val);
    int minutes = (int)Math.Round((val - hours) * 100);

    return new TimeSpan((int)hours, minutes, 0);
}

....
TimeSpan ts1 = GetTimeSpan(val);
TimeSpan ts2 = GetTimeSpan(val1);

TimeSpan diff = ts1 - ts2;

double resultHours = Math.Floor(diff.TotalHours) + ((double)diff.Minutes/100);
```

Result will be 119.30

Comment: I have 10 employees and their total working hours per day is 150.20 and I want to subtract 30.50 hours from the total. So the total output should on hours and not day

Comment: So why not use double hours = 150.20-30.50?

Comment: When I subtract direct it gives 119.7 but when we subtract this as time hours then the answer will be 119.40

Comment: Please explain exactly what the .20 in 150.20 means. 20 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan dt1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(150.20);
TimeSpan dt2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(30.50);
TimeSpan difference = dt1 - dt2;
Label1.Text = difference.Hours.ToString() + ":" + difference.Minutes.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirement completely but think that these hours are from a reference time

If that is the case, try this

```
    double val = 150.20;
    double val1 = 30.50;

    DateTime referenceTime = DateTime.Now; // Or whatever is the time since when you have the hours 
    DateTime valDateTime = referenceTime.AddHours(val);
    DateTime val1DateTime = referenceTime.AddHours(val1);

    double hours = Math.Abs((val1DateTime - valDateTime).TotalHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we consider that `Val` and `Val1` is based on hours the result on `TimeSpan` as below:

```
        double val = 150.20;
        double val1 = 30.50;

        TimeSpan x = TimeSpan.FromHours(val);
        TimeSpan y = TimeSpan.FromHours(val1);

        double res =   x.Subtract(y).TotalHours;   // Display 119.7
```

If we assume that `Val` and `Val1` is `Days` Result is below:

```
        double val = 150.20;
        double val1 = 30.50;

        TimeSpan x = TimeSpan.FromDays(val);
        TimeSpan y = TimeSpan.FromDays(val1);

        double res = x.Subtract(y).TotalHours;   // Display 2872.8
```